# Resolving Hosting Configuration Issue and Accessing Folders Outside the Root Directory

Tags: php, html, server, configuration, hosting

I need a suggestion on how to solve this issue or a suggestion on where to host my website.
I tried hosting it on a local provider and had a configuration problem as the provider does not allow access to a folder that is outside the root directory.
In my case, the root directory is 'public', but I have, for example, frameworks installed by Composer in a 'vendor' folder that is at the same level as 'public', and I can't access the files within because in the requests that are made, the server replaces the folder paths up to 'vendor' with the site's URL, like this: 'www.mysite.com/vendor/...'.
Since 'vendor' is not in the public folder, I can't access the files that are requested via script in this way:
In the config.php file, I define the 'Doc_root' path like this:
`define('ROOT_FOLDER', 'public');  $this_folder = substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));  $parent_folder = dirname($this_folder);  define("DOC_ROOT", $parent_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ROOT_FOLDER . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`
and I request the files on the HTML pages like this:

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: I request the files on the HTML pages like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{doc_root}}vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

Comment: You can not use HTTP to access files outside of the document root. Not directly, at least - you would have to write your own bridge/proxy, to make that possible. But that would be the wrong way to go about this in the first place - you need to fix your system's setup.